# Split String to float and string

Tags: java, regex, split

How can i split 100.26kg to System.out.println as

```
100.26
kg
```

I tried doing by using ("\d+") but was not successful.

```
String[] num = myTextCount.split("\\d+");
```

The 100.26kg may vary according to user input. It could be 100.26kg, 100g, 100 pounds or 100litre. If there is any way to split the number and alphabet, it will be very helpful

Comment: If it has a fixed format of `#kg` where `#` is any number, don't use regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputs[] = { "100.26kg", "100g", "100 pounds", "100litre"};

        String weight, unit;

        for(String input : inputs){
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);
            weight = scan.findInLine("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
            unit = scan.next();//scan.next("\\w+");

            System.out.println(weight);
            System.out.println(unit);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try *look-around* regex,

```
  String[] num = myTextCount.split("(?<=\\d)(?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=\\d)");
```

If you want to split `case-insensitive` with number than use `(?i)`

```
 String[] num = myTextCount.split("(?i)(?<=\\d)(?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=\\d)");
```

Comment: kg is not fixed format. It can be pounds, gallon, litre and etc. That's why i need to split the integer and the string

Answer (score 1):

`myTextCount.split("[\\.\\d]+")` will give you [, kg] which contain the second part, and then use #indexOf() to find the first part.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `Split`, just use the `String.IndexOf()` function to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^([0-9.]+)\\s*([a-zA-Z]+)$").matcher("");
String inputs[] = {"100.26kg", "1 pound", "98gallons" };

for(String input: inputs)
{
    if ( m.reset(input).find() )
    {
        System.out.printf("amount=[%s] unit=[%s]\n", m.group(1), m.group(2) );
    }
}
```

yields:

```
amount=[100.26] unit=[kg]
amount=[1] unit=[pound]
amount=[98] unit=[gallons]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
private static final Pattern VALID_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+|[A-Z]+");

private List<String> parse(String toParse) {
    List<String> chunks = new LinkedList<String>();
    Matcher matcher = VALID_PATTERN.matcher(toParse);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        chunks.add( matcher.group() );
    }
    return chunks;
}
```

This solution is quite modular as well.

Comment: it doesn't work for `.` values i.e `23.42` also for lower case characters